# Win32: Error with CreateTextServices

Tags: winapi, linker, richedit

I'm trying to use `CreateTextServices` function in `TextServ.h`. It seem I have to link `riched20.lib` to project to use this function.
But when I add `riched20.lib` to *Linker/Input/Additional Depedencies*, VS say **error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'riched20.lib'**.
How to fix this error?
I'm using VS 2013, Win 8.1 32 bit.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Where is the lib file? Can you find it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It seem (I think) win 8.1 dont has that lib. All projects I download at codeproject.com have same problem.

Comment: Win 8.1 doesn't supply the lib files. They come with the SDK. I think you might be confused over what a lib file actually is.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. I think there's no lib available for recent versions of richedit/msftedit, but textserv.h provides a definition of the function, so what you can do without any need for an extra .lib is this:

```
// load the dll and get the function address
// PCreateTextServices is declared in textserv.h:
HMODULE h = LoadLibrary(L"msftedit.dll");
PCreateTextServices createTextServices = (PCreateTextServices)GetProcAddress(h, "CreateTextServices");
...

ITextServices svc*;
int hr = createTextServices(NULL, host, (IUnknown**)&svc);

...
svc->Release();
FreeLibrary(h);
```